# Como executar o ProcessList periodicamente na linha de comando?

Tags: mysql, linux

Existe alguma maneira de ver o comando `SHOW PROCESSLIST` de X em X segundos, pela linha de comando?

Eu estou usando o Sistema Operacional Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Se usar o `watch SHOW PROCESSLIST ` pode ver de x em x segundos (inclusive pode especificar o tempo), se eu entendi sua pergunta corretamente :p

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `mysqladmin -u root -p -i 1 processlist`, onde:

- `-u` usuário
- `-p` será perguntada a senha
- `-i 1` intervalo em segundos

O resultado será algo parecido com isso:

```
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| 76 | root | localhost |    | Query   | 0    | starting | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+----------+------------------+
```

referência: [*MySQL: Show processlist every second*](https://zeldor.biz/2010/11/mysql-show-processlist-every-second/)